# $l^2+m^2=n^2$ $\implies$ $lm$ is always a multiple of 3 when $l,m,n,$ are positive integers.

Tags: number-theory

Let $l,m,n$ be any three positive integers such that $l^2+m^2=n^2$

Then prove that $lm$ is always a multiple of 3.

Comment: Either $lm$ is a multiple of three or it isn't, one doesn't say it "always" is. We could say that $l^2+m^2=n^2$ *always implies* that $lm$ is a multiple of three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We show that $3$ must divde $lm$, by showing that $3$ divides $l$ or $3$ divides $m$.

Any integer $x$ is either divisible by $3$, or is congruent to $1$ or $-1$ modulo $3$. And iff $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{3}$, then $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

Thus if neither $l$ nor $m$ is divisible by $3$, then $l^2+m^2\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. It follows that $l^2+m^2$ cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: How does it matter whether $l^2+m^2$ is a perfect square or not?

Comment: $l^2+m^2=n^2$ with $n$ integer...

Comment: Because we are told that $l^2+m^2=n^2$, a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. The general solution of this equation is:

$l = x^2 - y^2$, $m = 2xy$, $n = x^2 + y^2$. So: $l\cdot m = 2\cdot (x^2 - y^2)\cdot x\cdot y = 2\cdot (x - y)\cdot (x + y) \cdot x\cdot y$. From this, we have some cases to consdier:

1. $3|x$ or $3|y$ then $3|l\cdot m$.
2. $3 \not|x$ and $3\not|y$ then if $x \equiv y \pmod 3$, then $3|(x - y)$ and $(x - y)|l\cdot m$, so $3|l\cdot m$, but if $x \neq y \pmod 3$, then $x + y \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, and this implies that $3|l\cdot m$

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic resides modulo $3$ are $0$ and $1$. In other words, each of $l^2, m^2$ must be equivalent to either $ 0, 1\pmod3$.

However, $l^2$ and $m^2$ cannot both be equivalent to $1$ modulo 3, because their sum , $n^2$, a perfect square, would be equivalent to $2\pmod3$, a quadratic non-residue.

Hence, at least one of $l^2, m^2$ must be equivalent to $0\pmod3$. As such $l^2m^2 = (lm)^2 \equiv 0\pmod 3$. By Euclid's lemma, $lm \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.